# How to hide label from the top of the columns in MSChart

Tags: c#, mschart

I've got a Chart Control column chart in my application (C# .NET). There are 16 columns in the chart, which are added by creating Datapoint objects dynamically. Each Datapoint has a Label property which should be shown in the tooltip with #LABEL. This works just fine, however the labels are automatically shown above the columns making the chart 'crowded'. How can I get rid of them?

EDIT: Here is a pic:

[image: Pic]

Comment: Don't set the labels and set the tooltips for each datapoint when you create them instead of using the #LABEL variable! Or maybe you can cheat with the lables' forecolor?

Comment: Sorry: your first tip. I dismissed the Label property at all and set the Tooltip property for each DataPoint.